# Haskell multiple monomorphic containers in one library

Tags: haskell, containers, naming-conventions

I have a library project, with quite few specialized monomorphic containers (mostly sets and also some map-like). They all share the basic Set functioanality (empty, singleton, insert, union etc), but also have additional value-specific functions. Some of them are just wrappers around Data.Set, but others need more efficient implementations (like finite bitset). I have 2 questions:

1. What are the pros and cons of suffixing every such function (emptyT, singletonU)? Would it make a good general practice to suffix all monomorphic container functions to easier differentiate between them, and the polymorphic ones?
2. Here is some sample code.

   ```
   import qualified Data.Set as S

   data T = ...

   newtype TSet = TSet { unpack :: S.Set T }

   emptyT = TSet S.empty

   singletonT = TSet . S.singleton
   ```

Is this the right way to wrap around polymorphic containers? Is there any more clever way to "inherit" functionality? I thought about creating a custom Set typeclass, but after reading some posts here I see it would only overcomplicate things..

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use a module for each monomorphic specialization.
Consider modules names `Data.Set.Specialized.Int`, `Data.Set.Specialized.Char` etc.
Reuse, as much as possible, the same names used in `Data.Set`, without any suffix.
Make your modules be used with `import qualified`, as `Data.Set`.

Advantages:

- users are already familiar with the names
- if one wants to change their `Data.Set` code to the specialized variant, this be dome simply by changing the types, from e.g.

  ```
  import qualified Data.Set as S
  foo :: S.Set Int -> String
  ```

  to

  ```
  import qualified Data.Set.Specialized.Int as SI
  foo :: SI.Set -> String
  ```

  without touching the code.

A typeclass is also a possibility, but one needs to be careful to choose the common operations among all variants. Also, if I understand correctly, you still want to allow some sets to have special operations which are not available for other sets. These much be outside the hypothetical type class, of course.

For question 2: if the wrapping is a `newtype` around `Data.Set`, you should consider [safe coercions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html).

```
module Data.Set.Specialized.Int where

import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.Coerce

newtype Set = Set { unSet :: S.Set Int }

union :: Set -> Set -> Set
union = coerce S.union
```

Comment: I apologise for not making it clear. The library is NOT about specialized containers for standard types. It is for writing useful code in domain X, that in turn has datatypes T,U,V... specialized to domain X and useless in the context of the standard library.